# Why is using "xgbTree" in caret so slow with trainControl?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to fit xgboost model on multiclass prediction problem, and wanted to use `caret` to do hyperparameter search. 
To test the package, I used the following code, and it takes takes 20 seconds, when I do not supply `train` object with trainControl

```
# just use one parameter combination
xgb_grid_1 <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = 1,
  eta = 0.3,
  max_depth = 5,
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree=1, 
  min_child_weight=1
)
# train
xgb_train_1 = train(
  x = as.matrix(sparse_train),
  y = conversion_tbl$y_train_c ,
  trControl = trainControl(method="none", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = multiClassSummary),
  metric="logLoss",
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid_1,
  method = "xgbTree"
)
```

However, when I supply `train` with a trainControl object, the code never gets finished..or taking a long time(at least it dint' finish for 15 minutes.

```
xgb_trcontrol_1 <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 2,
  verboseIter = TRUE, 
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "none",                                         
  classProbs = TRUE,                                           
  summaryFunction = multiClassSummary
)
xgb_train_1 = train(
  x = as.matrix(sparse_train),
  y = conversion_tbl$y_train_c ,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,
  metric="logLoss",
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid_1,
  method = "xgbTree"
)
```

Why is this?

FYI, my data size is

```
 dim(sparse_train)
[1] 702402     36
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: I've noticed the exact same thing.  Putting trainControl() directly into the train() object rather than setting it to its own variable first, drastically improves the speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your trainControl objects are different.

In the first trainControl object, the method is `method="none"`.
In the second trainControl object, the method is `method="cv"` and `number=2`. So, in the second object, you are running a two-fold cross-validation which takes longer then not running a cross-validation.

Comment: That's true, but I wouldn't expect it to increase the time from 20 seconds to 15+ minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you can try is adding `nthread = 1` to the `caret::train()` call.

Both XGBoost and Caret try to use parallel/multicore processing where possible, and in the past I have found this to (silently) cause too many threads to spawn, throttling your machine.

Telling caret to process models in sequence minimizes the problem and should mean that only xgboost will be spawning threads.